# How to fix ALDialog Python Script NAOqi Error

Tags: python, nao-robot, choregraphe

I am trying to use ALDialog module to have a virtual conversation with the Choregraphe simulated NAO6 robot. I have the below script:

```
import qi
import argparse
import sys

def main(session):
    """
    This example uses ALDialog methods.
    It's a short dialog session with two topics.
    """
    # Getting the service ALDialog
    ALDialog = session.service("ALDialog")
    ALDialog.setLanguage("English")

    # writing topics' qichat code as text strings (end-of-line characters are important!)
    topic_content_1 = ('topic: ~example_topic_content()\n'
                       'language: enu\n'
                       'concept:(food) [fruits chicken beef eggs]\n'
                       'u: (I [want "would like"] {some} _~food) Sure! You must really like $1 .\n'
                       'u: (how are you today) Hello human, I am fine thank you and you?\n'
                       'u: (Good morning Nao did you sleep well) No damn! You forgot to switch me off!\n'
                       'u: ([e:FrontTactilTouched e:MiddleTactilTouched e:RearTactilTouched]) You touched my head!\n')

    topic_content_2 = ('topic: ~dummy_topic()\n'
                       'language: enu\n'
                       'u:(test) [a b "c d" "e f g"]\n')

    # Loading the topics directly as text strings
    topic_name_1 = ALDialog.loadTopicContent(topic_content_1)
    topic_name_2 = ALDialog.loadTopicContent(topic_content_2)

    # Activating the loaded topics
    ALDialog.activateTopic(topic_name_1)
    ALDialog.activateTopic(topic_name_2)

    # Starting the dialog engine - we need to type an arbitrary string as the identifier
    # We subscribe only ONCE, regardless of the number of topics we have activated
    ALDialog.subscribe('my_dialog_example')

    try:
        raw_input("\nSpeak to the robot using rules from both the activated topics. Press Enter when finished:")
    finally:
        # stopping the dialog engine
        ALDialog.unsubscribe('my_dialog_example')

        # Deactivating all topics
        ALDialog.deactivateTopic(topic_name_1)
        ALDialog.deactivateTopic(topic_name_2)

        # now that the dialog engine is stopped and there are no more activated topics,
        # we can unload all topics and free the associated memory
        ALDialog.unloadTopic(topic_name_1)
        ALDialog.unloadTopic(topic_name_2)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    session = qi.Session()
    try:
        session.connect("tcp://desktop-6d4cqe5.local:9559")
    except RuntimeError:
        print ("\nCan't connect to Naoqi at IP desktop-6d4cqe5.local(port 9559).\nPlease check your script's arguments."
               " Run with -h option for help.\n")
        sys.exit(1)
    main(session, "desktop-6d4cqe5.local")
```

My simulated robot has desktop-6d4cqe5.local as IP address and its NAOqi port is running on 63361. I want to run the dialogs outside of the Choregraphe in a python script and only be able to use the dialog box within the Choregraphe to test it. When I ran the above python file I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Documents\...\choregraphe_codes\Welcome\speak.py", line 6, in <module>
    import qi
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pynaoqi\lib\qi\__init__.py", line 93
    async, PeriodicTask)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I couldn't figure out the problem as there was not much resources online and the robot's documentations are a bit hard to understand.

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the script using a Python version greater than 3.5, that sees `async` as a keyword, now.

NAOqi only supports Python 2.
Try running your script with `python2` explicitly.